# AvalonEdit: Determine if you are in a Comment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalonedit

For AvalonEdit I have defined "Comments" in the xshd-File. Now, in my program, I would like to determine whether a given offset lies inside or outside of a comment.

I did find some code on the net, namely:

 http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/12793.aspx

However, I do not know how to receive the necessary objects (like CurrentContext) from my AvalonEdit-Object.

I'm hoping someone has created such a function before. Can you please post some code or point me in the right direction? (documentation, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "current context" is in that example, but it's only used to access the service container with the `IHighlighter`.
You can get that directly from the TextEditor:

```
bool IsInComment(int line, int column)
{
    IHighlighter highlighter = textEditor.TextArea.GetService(typeof(IHighlighter)) as IHighlighter;
    if (highlighter == null)
        return false;
    int off = textEditor.Document.GetOffset(line, column);
    HighlightedLine result = highlighter.HighlightLine(document.GetLineByNumber(line));
    return result.Sections.Any(s => s.Offset <= off && s.Offset+s.Length >= off && s.Color.Name == "Comment");
}
```

Comment: The "GetService"-part was missing in my solution. Thank you! A small mistake: The line determining "result" needs just the linenumber and not the line as argument of HighlightLine